# Number of paths between any two distinct vertices is always same?

Tags: graph-theory

I've encountered this probably really easy problem.

"Let *u*, *v*, and *w* be any distinct vertices in $\ K_n $, for $\ n \geq 3 $.
Then, the number of simple distinct paths from *u* to *v* and *u* to *w* is same."

I get this must be true intuitively and I can count them easily, but I was wondering if there is any proof that doesn't involve directly counting the number of paths.

Thanks!

Comment: As Parcly’s answer shows, instead of counting the paths in both cases, we simply need to show objective correspondence between the two sets of paths. Indeed, “counting” is just showing a bijective correspondence between a given set and the first $n$ natural numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete graph $K_n$ has automorphisms sending $(u,v)$ to $(u,w)$ for any $u,v,w$ and $n\ge3$. Such automorphisms (any one can be chosen for the purpose of this proof) act on any simple path from $u$ to $v$, turning it into a path from $u$ to $w$, giving a bijection between the simple paths from $u$ to $v$ and those paths from $u$ to $w$. Thus the two numbers of paths must be equal.